# Proving $f_\alpha(x) = x^{-a} \in L^p((0,1))$ for $a > 0, ap < 1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

In Folland's book on real analysis he claims that the function $f_\alpha(x) = x^{-\alpha}$ is in $L^p((0,1))$ if $\alpha > 0$ and $\alpha p < 1$.

I tried to verify this directly:
$$\left[ \int_{(0,1)} |x^{-\alpha}|^pdx\right]^{1/p} = \left[ \int_{(0,1)} x^{-\alpha p}dx\right]^{1/p} \leq \left[ \int_{(0,1)} x^{-1}dx\right]^{1/p} = \left[ \log(1) - \log(0)\right]^{1/p} = \left[- \log(0)\right]^{1/p}$$
or another approch:
$$\left[ \int_{(0,1)} |x^{-\alpha}|^pdx\right]^{1/p} = \left[ \int_{(0,1)} x^{-\alpha p}dx\right]^{1/p} = \left[\left(\frac{1}{(x^{1-\alpha p})(1-\alpha p)}\right)\Big\vert_{x = 0}^{x=1}\right]^{1/p}.$$

However, in both cases the final expression will not be bounded, so how is this function in $L^p$? Based on the wording in the book I assume this should be trivial, so I must be overlooking something.

Comment: Notice that as long as $1-ap<0$, when you evaluate at the extreme points your integral is finite. For $ap=1$ you get a log-type integrand.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Ah yes, that was stupid of me not to notice. So the solution to the integral becomes $x^\gamma/(1-\alpha p)$ where $\gamma = \alpha p - 1 > 0$ and so it is simply a polynomial, in which case everything is bounded. Thank you!